# Can flags be retracted, and how in the Stack Exchange Android app?

Tags: support, flags, retracted-flags

Sometimes we raise a flag to someone's post for one of the reasons such as *spam*, *not clear*, *off-topic*, *etc*. After some time the post gets edited. Or we realize that a flag should not have been raised for this post.

To overcome this situation, is there a provision of rolling back the **Flag** mark on that Q&A post?

Because in that case the chance of the flag getting declined, is higher than the raised flag being marked "helpful".

I am unable to retract a marked flag in the Android app of Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can retract your flag click on the "flag" of the flagged post tan click on "Retract Flag" button. [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NJfi.png)

Comment: I have edited question so it should be opened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Flags can be retracted. Simply click on the "flag" link below the flagged post. A dialog will appear that tells you you've already flagged this post. In the lower righthand corner of this dialog, there is a button "Retract Flag".

Comment: I do not have the option to retract flags. I had several declined flags in short succession and now SO has locked me out of flagging, instead asking me to review my current declined flags, but I am unable to do anything about the declined flags.